# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection'

Tags: c#, config

I cannot figure out why i am getting this error. I am trying to get a value from appSettings section of a mapped config file.

Here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>    
    <!-- Need to configure.-->
    <add key="ServiceDisplayName" value="Scheduler-aaaa" />
    <add key="ServiceName" value="SchedulerService-aaaa" />
    <add key="SchedulerTime" value="05:00 AM" />
    <!-- 12 hour format-->
    <add key="RoutingInterval" value="5"/>
    <add key="ADSyncInterval" value="2"/>
    <add key="ReportPath" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aaaa\Reports\DefaultReports"/>
    <add key="ReportPathCustom" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aaaa\Reports\CustomReports"/>
    <add key="ApplicationUrl" value="https://mms.com/aaaa/"/>
    <add key="ServiceUrl" value="https://temp.com/aaaa/Inspection/Service"/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
    <add key="EmailAddress" value="support@mms.com" />
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CustomerDB" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=.\temp;User ID=mm;PWD=mm;Initial Catalog=35testupdate" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <cachingConfiguration />
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here is my code:

```
                ExeConfigurationFileMap fm = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(path);
                fm.ExeConfigFilename = path;//"Scheduler.exe.config";
                Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fm, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

                if (conf.AppSettings.Settings["SchedulerTime"] != null) //<<ERROR
                {
                    return conf.AppSettings.Settings["SchedulerTime"].Value;
                }
```

I have tried just getting the section of appSettings, but it is null when i do this:

```
conf.GetSection("appSettings");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution:

Changed my code to the following:

```
            ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = path;
            Configuration conf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

            if (conf.AppSettings.Settings["SchedulerTime"] != null) //<<ERROR
            {
                return conf.AppSettings.Settings["SchedulerTime"].Value;
            }
```

Just removing the argument to the ExeConfigurationFileMap instance on the first line fixed the issue. Thought i would post my answer if this helps anyone.